# ClamTK and Encrypted Home Directory

Tags: ecryptfs, clamav, clamtk

I recently encrypted my home directory and since then I have realized Clam AV is not really scanning the file in my home directory. It is scanning the encrypted files. I am running the scan with the user who's home is encrypted (using `ecryptfs-migrate-home`).

[image]

**How can I recursively scan my encrypted home directory now using `ClamTK` or `freshclam`?**

Comment: You can't scan encrypted files, you have to decrypt them, then scan them

Comment: Agreed, but for all use other than the virus scan the contents of the home directory are automatically decrypted without me having to explicitly take any action to decrypt. Why won’t that be the case while virus scanning?

Comment: You are asking why clamav or any virus scanner does not have decryption as a feature ? Really ? It would be poor encryption if clamav could decrypt the data.

Comment: No, the decryption is at the point when the user who’s home is encrypted logs in. The user doesn’t need to decrypt individual files to use. I am expecting the same from the antivirus for reading files during the scan.

Comment: user logs in  -> files are decrypted. Then step  run clamav. Exclude the encrypted files if you wish (.Private I think)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that when setup as a cron job to run at 2AM, as daily scans should be, the application needs the smarts to decrypt a home folder. Many users now encrypt the home folder or the whole disk. From the login, scanning just ~/.mozilla, ~/.thunderbird, and ~/Downloads (4.1GB) took significant time, maybe an hour, running about 50% CPU on a dual core machine and Ubuntu 18.04. That is not an efficient use of resources when you are logged in trying to get other tasks accomplished.